# Delete item from both, database and listview on clicking Delete Button

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to delete an item permanently from ListView and then from database. I have a DatabaseHandler.java class, which has the delete function as:

```
// Deleting single contact, in DatabaseHandler.java class
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

Then I have a FriendList.java class, when the user's friends are displayed as an item in ListView. When I long press on an item, then I get the option of "Delete" and "Cancel" in Dialog Box. Now, when I click on delete, the item is deleted from the ListView, but, not from the database. How can I delete it from database as well?
The code for getting the option of "Delete" and "Cancel"

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
              int position, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  Intent i = new Intent(FriendList.this, Delete_Confirm.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  //I am sending position of listitem in putExtra below//     
          i.putExtra("position", position);
          startActivityForResult(i,CONFIRM);
          item2 = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);


          //Toast.makeText(FriendList.this, "Clicked"+item2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          int l = item2.length();
          c=0;
          for(int j=0; j<=l; j++){
              if(item2.charAt(j) != '9' || item2.charAt(j+1) != '1'){
                  c++;                   
              }
              else {
                  //Do nothing
                  break;
              }
              num = item2.substring(c, l);  

          }


          Toast.makeText(FriendList.this, "Clicked: "+num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;


      }
      });
```

The corresponding code for onActivityResult is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
  case (CONFIRM) :
  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
      int posi = data.getIntExtra("position",0);
          Log.d("msg","position is " + posi);

          Log.d("msg","Do we reach here?");
          final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    //db.deleteContact(posi);
                    list.remove(posi);

                  listview.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


  }

    break;

}}
```

Please suggest how can I delete it from database as well. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:
On uncommenting db.deleteContact(posi), I get the following error:
The method deleteContact(Contact) in the type DatabaseHandler is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Note that the function deleteContact has contact variable of the type Contact.

Comment: Why db.deleteContact(posi) is commented out?

Comment: @SnapDragon: Because it was not deleting the contact from database and I have no idea why :(. It was causing the App to crash, so, I commented it to continue with debugging.

Comment: please post the logs when the app crashes

Comment: @user1903022 just uncomment that line and post the stack trace.

Comment: @KrupalShah, Priyank Gupta: Please refer the edit.

Comment: @user1903022, Dont acces DB in UI thread.
This can cause the crash.

Comment: @user1903022 put the whole crash logs.

Comment: @KrupalShah: It's not crashing now, just giving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete.... Try Deleting **first** from **database** then from **ListView**..

example:

```
 db.deleteContact(list.get(posi));  // this will get string  
 list.remove(posi);
```

**DatabaseHandler class.......**

```
public void deleteContact(String name){
    Log.d("Name:",""+ name);
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_NAME + " = ?", new String[] { name });

}
```

Comment: It's giving the error as shown in the EDIT part of the question. The problem is that the data type are different.

Comment: I edited my Answer try... once...........@user1903022 try changing contact to string

Comment: It is deleting the item from the ListView, however, after deleting when I close the App and open the App again, the deleted contact is visible again.

Comment: Did you try changing the codes i edited my anwser....your deleteContact(to string) and don't comment db.deleteContact(list.get(posi));

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you had suggested.
final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                        
              db.deleteContact(list.get(posi));  
              Log.i("DB check", "DB check"+ list.get(posi) );
              list.remove(posi);
              listview.setAdapter(adapter);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Can u show ur log....where the error is coming...... and hope you ve change your  DatabaseHandler.java  class tooo..

Comment: Yes, I had changed my Database Handler too. The App is compiling properly, but, when you reopen the App, after deleting the item, the deleted item appears again. When I click on Delete/Cancel button, I do get an error, though it's not related to db, but it has been attached for your reference in the question. Please refer the EDIT2.

Comment: Solved it. The issue was "db.deleteContact(list.get(posi));" was returning the complete string, something like "Rahul: 919876543219", what we needed to pass was just "Rahul". So, I extracted the name, passed it and it worked like charm. You might want to modify your answer, so that, I may accept it, because, ultimately, you guided me in the right direction.

Comment: See my method I wrote only String "name"....in the argument...and to check Log.d("Name:",""+ name); cause ur database won't ve both name...and contact number stored in one cell...if it was then its a bad way of storing....:D So you can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Its a compilation error. 
You need to pass a Contact object to the method, not an integer.

Comment: 'Id' would be an integer type, so, what kind of change would you suggest in deleteContact(contact) function, so that the integer value of posi can work?

Comment: @user1903022, get the id of the row and not the position from the adapter, then pass it instead of `contact.getID())`

Comment: Could you please give an example with code. I am new to Android, would appreciate if you could help with an example.

Comment: You need to create a contact object and pass that in as an argument.  However you can't just pass in the listview position as an ID to delete from the db as won't necessarily match the correct database ID.  Have you thought about using a cursor adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that position is not the corresponding id in the database. A possible solution would be to add a tag with the database id of the contact you have in this listitem. And when you remove it you get the tag with the id and delete the item from the database.

Edit (added clarification):

I would add in your listviewadapter something like:

```
yourcontactview.setTag(contact.getId());
```

in which you add to your view a tag with the database id of the corresponding contact.

Then where you delete the contact I would get the contact you want to delete with something like this:

```
Contact deletecontact = db.getContact(view.getTag());
db.deleteContact(deletecontact);
```

Of course you could change your 
deleteContact(Contact contact) to a method in which you give the id instead of  the contactobject.

This should hopefully work.

Comment: Could you please give an example. I am new to Android, some example with code would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete from database first then from ListView. And suggest Iterator to remove list element.