# How To Delete ListView Item from Database on LongClick?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio

I create a Listview which is populated from SQLite database, and Long Click, on ListView Item I provide a DialogBox with two Button Delete and cancel. On click on Delete Button I want to delete that ListView item from SQLite Database.But I did not add any Primary Key in a database. So how to delete it by its Item Position.

Comment: after delete from database, reload ListView, call notifyDataChanged function to reload list, and for primary key, first get item with selected position and then get the primary key

Comment: I also Do that but its deleted from listview item not from database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771636/delete-item-from-both-database-and-listview-on-clicking-delete-button

Comment: **Integer deleteItem= databaseHelper.delete_byID();** this line where you are passing clicked positioid and the condition you are passing is not correct way.

Comment: condition like is table row deleted or not

Comment: please post your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Object> items = query from sqlite; <--- notice
then set items to listView adapter
enter code here
```

in onitem click

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, final int **position**, long arg3)
{

    ....
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


         Integer deleteItem= 
          databaseHelper.delete_byID
            (items.get(**position**).primaryKey); <----- change this

                        if(deleteItem>0)

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }
                });
        builder.show();][1]
```

and reload Listview to remove it from listView too;

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it in text-view with visibility  `View.GONE`

Comment: in List view add one more text-view with visibility gone and get your id  on-click of list-view and pass it in to your Query